# Is there a work around for Visual Studio team services code coverage publishing stripping style sheets

Tags: code-coverage, azure-devops

We use code coverage reports generated by karma. I don't think it's related, but we also run this coverage through istanbul to map the coverage back to TypeScript. Previously, these results were published as the coverage report for the builds run by Visual Studio team services. In the code coverage section of the build report, these reports used to display perfectly.

Around 9/6/2016, the display of this report in the build began stripping the stylesheet tags from the report displayed in a frame on the site. Downloading the report and viewing it in a browser shows the correct stylesheet tags in the original report.

Has anyone using this feature of team services noticed the change? Do you have a work around for this? The styled reports made them very useful color coding coverage results.

I've asked this question in the team services uservoice, but haven't seen any activity: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15926806-code-coverage-report-on-build-should-not-strip-sty

Comment: You can provide the screenshots here.

Comment: What's the reports like? What're build steps of build definition? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is been take back due to security issue. Please refer to this link for details: [Code coverage became delete link and meta tags.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2357)

> We’re sorry we’ve caused you pain. We realise this appears to be a
>   takeback. We took this step because discovered a vulnerability and had
>   to take immediate action for your security before any public
>   disclosure. The current state is a stopgap and we are investigating
>   the right, secure way to restore the user experience. We will share
>   more about this in a blog post shortly.
>
> Note: you can still use the "Download Coverage Results" link to
>   download the html files and browse locally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are workarounds to achieve the styles(look & feel). Once coverage reports are generated, you can trigger a Gulp, Grunt or node tasks etc., to read the external CSS and write them with  tags in the actual report HTML.

There are various implementations mentioned through different article. You can check those listed here -> [code coverage html reports are missing styles in VSTS](https://davidsekar.com/aspnetcore/code-coverage-html-reports-are-missing-styles-in-vsts)

Link to an NPM package I created for solving just this specific problem
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-coverage-styles